# MySQL Workbench EER Diagramm - how to change storage engine?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I use MySQL Workbench 5.2.38. and I have made an EER Diagram. But on export I got surprised with InnoDB as defined storage engine. Altering the table afterwards is not an option because I do not have an InnoDB engine.

ERROR 1286 (42000): Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'

So, I have changed the Default Engine via Edit-> Preferences -> Model: MySQL to MyISAM but on export there is still InnoDB in use?!

I am completely unable to find the option to change the storage engine in table editor. Can someone help me how I can change the storage engine for my tables in MySQL Workbench ERR?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It's not very obvious but when editing a table there is a blue arrow on the right. If you click this you get more options where you can alter the storage engine.

[image]

Comment: That's indeed not very obvious. Thanks alot for the hint!

Comment: I thought it would hide the options :D

Answer (score 1):

Global preferences should be respected by default in the Workbench Model Editor. If not, you should [file a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com) about this issue.

However, here's another solution that I've tried and it worked:

1. In the Model Editor go to `Model --> Model Options...`
2. Uncheck the `Use Global Settings` checkbox at the bottom of the dialog that appeared.
3. Go to the `Model: MySQL` tab and select in the `Default Storage Engine` combo box the storage engine you'd like to use.

Once you do this the generated script will use the storage engine you selected.

Comment: Thanks, I have filed a Bug (64928). I have found a workaround solution. Export the model to sql file. search replace the storage engine in the sql file with a text editor. reverse engineer the modyfied sql in workbench. not smart but works.